# Finding Average by Replacing Text Values with Numbers Using Array and Not Let()

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet that looks like the following:

```
+-----------+------+-----------+------+----------------+
| Average   | Life | Age       | Life | Age            |
+-----------+------+-----------+------+----------------+
| Young     | Blah | Young     | Blah | Old            |
+-----------+------+-----------+------+----------------+
| Young     | Blah | Old       | Blah | Young          |
+-----------+------+-----------+------+----------------+
| Super Old | Blah | Super Old | Blah | Should Be Dead |
+-----------+------+-----------+------+----------------+
```

Consider the `Average` column - I want this to get the data from the `Age` columns (please note that age columns can exist anywhere in the sheet, the alternate representation above is merely for easy visualizing).

I want to encode `Young = 0, Old = 1 ... Should Be Dead = 3` and then put an average based on range, like between `0 and 1 (included) = Young` etc.

This is easily doable in VBA, but I was wondering is it even possible to do it using a formula?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Microsoft365 you can create a nice re-usable variable through `LET()`:

[image]

Formula in `A2`:

```
=LET(X,{"Young","Old","Super Old","Should Be Dead"},INDEX(X,MATCH(AVERAGE(MATCH(C2,X,0)-1,MATCH(E2,X,0)-1),{0,1,2,3})))
```

Where `MATCH(C2,X,0)-1` (up to more than two arguments) is all these different columns you can refer to in your scenario.

Note that you don't really need `LET()` here, it's just .... handy.

Without `LET()`:

```
=INDEX({"Young","Old","Super Old","Should Be Dead"},MATCH(AVERAGE(MATCH(C2,{"Young","Old","Super Old","Should Be Dead"},0)-1,MATCH(E2,{"Young","Old","Super Old","Should Be Dead"},0)-1),{0,1,2,3}))
```

Comment: Ah, sadly I have no `LET` function (even after having O365, but I don't know :( )

Comment: @Jishan, you may need to just run an update. Either way, you can obviously keep that out and use the array where it says "X".

Comment: `you can obviously keep that out and use the array where it says "X"` - can you show an example please, thanks a lot :)